# What is the difference between an Entity and a Persistent Object in App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I am fairly new to App Engine and I am trying to figure out how to store and retrieve data. However, I am confused about the difference between a java class marked with @Entity(name="name") and a class marked with @PersistenceCapable. What is the difference between these two if I am trying to store something which can be sent off to a client? For example, if I have an API which makes a list of Cars available for rental, would I use an Entity or a PersistenceCapable class for the Car object?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `@Entity` is part of JPA and `@PersistencCapable` is JDO. Hence you might want to read this discussion about JPA vs JDO: https://db.apache.org/jdo/jdo_v_jpa.html

Comment: So App Engine treats them as they normally are treated? Finding complete tutorials on it has been near impossible thus far.